# Get point around rounded rectangle

Tags: c++

I'm using this to get a point around a circle.

```
constexpr int quality = 20;

static Vertex_t verts[quality];

for ( int i = 0; i < quality; i++ ) {
    float angle = ((float)i / -quality) * MATH_TAU;

    verts[i].x = cir.pos.x + (cir.radius * sin( angle ));
    verts[i].y = cir.pos.y + (cir.radius * cos( angle ));
}
```

now i need to get a point around a rounded rectangle given it's position, size and radius.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to split the code to 4 - one for each corner. As these are vertices you're dealing with, the straight lines will be filled automatically.